# XMLRPC error: xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'>

Tags: plugins, xml-rpc

Just downloaded wordpress latest, using LAMP (Apache2/MariaDB and PHP8.2) and curling it returns this

```
curl http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php; echo
XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.
curl -X POST http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php; echo
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name>
          <value><int>-32700</int></value>
        </member>
        <member>
          <name>faultString</name>
          <value><string>parse error. not well formed</string></value>
        </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

It seems running. When I use python client

```
>>> from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
>>> c = Client('http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/xmlrpc.php', 'wordpressuser', 'wordpressuser69$')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/wordpress_xmlrpc/base.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.supported_methods = self.server.mt.supportedMethods()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1122, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1464, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1182, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1354, in parse_response
    return u.close()
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/xmlrpc/client.py", line 668, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'>
>>>
```

The user and password is valid and I am testing in localhost for now but error isnt expected here I think. Do you know what could be the problem? I am using someone else library and it fails at xmlrpc. The library has bugs which I fixed but now its in this xmlrpc error https://github.com/seedgularity/AIBlogPilotGPT. ChatGPT gave me sample code to check if its working or not

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client

wp = Client('http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php', 'wordpressuser', 'wordpressuser69$')
print(wp.call('system.listMethods'))
```

but even the client part is giving me errors. Both `Client('http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php', 'wordpressuser', 'wordpressuser69$')` and `Client('http://127.0.0.1:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php', 'wordpressuser', 'wordpressuser69$')` gives me error.

This seemingly valid request also produces error:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php -d '<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>system.listMethods</methodName></methodCall>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name>
          <value><int>-32700</int></value>
        </member>
        <member>
          <name>faultString</name>
          <value><string>parse error. not well formed</string></value>
        </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

I also do not see any xmlrpc checkboxes in `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-writing.php`. Afaik, xmlrpc is enabled by default. But still I tried putting this line in `define('XMLRPC_REQUEST', true);` in wp-config.php file and it breaks, admin page is undisplayable but if i remove this line admin page is displayable.

Could it be related to bad apache2 configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf`. This is the content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@your_domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ServerName your_domain.com
    ServerAlias www.your_domain.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the command issued after writing this. I havent changed anything in conf since I am testing in localhost not VPS where I plan to deploy the website after buying a domain

```
sudo a2ensite wordpress.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: XMLRPC is quite an old API, is there a reason you didn't use the more modern and feature complete REST API?

Comment: https://github.com/seedgularity/AIBlogPilotGPT The plugin uses xmlrpc to upload posts so fixing possible error would be less hassle than rewriting that code in rest api. I will look into rewriting it though if possible

Comment: from what I can see it makes up a tiny portion and is isolated to `post_to_wordpress` in `orchestrar/gutenberg.py` and is covered in warnings that it's for testing only. A version that makes a `POST` request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/post` with an application password http header might actually be smaller. Eitherway the chance that this is related to anything Apache is very very low, and there's also a chance your host has blocked XMLRPC queries but since the XMLRPC API replied to tell you your message was malformed that too is unlikely

Comment: also noting that I tried your curl command on my own site and it worked just fine. You might also want to check your PHP error log, some of the failure cases for the IXR Message parse method involve missing PHP functions/modules https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/IXR/class-IXR-message.php#L45

Comment: I noticed /wp-json folder is missing as well. I tried installing rest api plugin but it failed, setup ftp server, gave all permissions. Installed and activated the plugin but configuring both JWT or basic authentication failed and curling wp-json gave 404.

Comment: Actually you are right; enabling debug logs shows this `[16-Jan-2024 09:34:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  PHP's XML extension is not available. Please contact your hosting provider to enable PHP's XML extension. in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/IXR/c    lass-IXR-message.php on line 48`. Looks like some PHP module is missing

Answer (score 1):

Enabling PHP logging and reading logs showed the problem, thanks to Tom.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

```
[16-Jan-2024 09:34:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  PHP's XML extension is not available. Please contact your hosting provider to enable PHP's XML extension. in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/IXR/c    lass-IXR-message.php on line 48
```

A simple apt install php-xml fixed it

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:80/wordpress/xmlrpc.php -d '<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>system.listMethods</methodName></methodCall>' | head
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
      <array><data>
  <value><string>system.multicall</string></value>
  <value><string>system.listMethods</string></value>
  <value><string>system.getCapabilities</string></value>
  <value><string>demo.addTwoNumbers</string></value>
100  4361  100  4272  100    89   173k   3709 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  185k
curl: Failed writing body
```

Python client also doesn't error now